# Is it possible to take a thread dump of CloudDataflow java process?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

After I ssh using cloud console
I used docker ps to list the containers

then did the following
docker exec -it  jstack, but it throws the following error

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec:
>   \"jstack\": executable file not found in $PATH

Also I don't find jstack inside the container.
So Is there an easy way to take a thread dump of a cloud dataflow javastreaming process.

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow workers host a local debugging http server on port 8081. When you ssh to the worker, you can do `curl http://localhost:8081/threadz` and it should give you the thread stacks.

We're working on providing better ways to surface worker stuckness to the users, but for now this is the only way.

Comment: Thank you so much, But Is it available in documentation? I searched through the docs and don't find this information. Thank you again.

Comment: No, this is an undocumented / unsupported / "use at your own risk" low-level tool, albeit a very useful one. We are working on better and higher-level tools ways for debugging issues like this and others in Dataflow pipelines.